# display flex does't work and impossible to centered the div

Tags: flexbox, center, display

here my test
https://jsfiddle.net/Artenis/nozv1nsf/#&togetherjs=yjibGnfDFM

could you please tell me where is my error

i would like the div which contain text (black opacity) is centered horizontally and vertically in relation to the background-image. The div with background-color black opacity won't take the total height but just the padding of div of text.
this same div must be take all the width of the background.
I use

```
display:flex; justify-content:center; and content-align:center;
```

so far it has always worked, but not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your problem.

```
.moncontenu{  color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-shadow: 2px 4px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 33pt;width:100%; padding: 15px 0px !important; align-self: center;}
```

(added **align-self: center;**)

Comment: thanks, that resolve the position of the text, but the height of the div take always the height of the background-image.

Comment: alright, it's good, i have integer your solution : align-self:center, inside the div wich contain .moncontenu. .bloccentragecontenu